# Couldn't find "arm-elf-g++" while debugging

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, compilation, arduino

I am trying to develope a small c++ programm in Eclipse for my Arduino (Teensy).

My problem is when I compile it I get the following error:

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/main.cpp
/bin/sh: 1: arm-elf-g++: not found
make: *** [src/main.o] Fehler 127
Invoking: ARM Linux GCC C++ Compiler (GNUARM)
arm-elf-g++ -DF_CPU=96000000 -DUSB_SERIAL -DLAYOUT_US_ENGLISH -I"/home/darcade/workspace/TeensyCore3/src" -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -Wa,-adhlns="src/main.o.lst" -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/main.d" -MT"src/main.d" -o "src/main.o" "../src/main.cpp"

21:17:05 Build Finished (took 124ms)
```

I searched on my pc for "arm-elf-g++", but I didn't find anything...

I am running Debian Testing on my PC.

Hope you'll help me.

lg Darcade

Comment: Then you simply haven't installed the cross compiler needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which Teensy do you have?  From the error, looks like you are trying to compile for the ARM Cortex (Teensy 3.0).  If you haven't already, download compilers: http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_download.html and then make sure that the installed compilers (especially where arm-elf-g++) is in your $PATH.